# Magento 2 How to stop particular group cron?

Tags: magento2, cron, command

I runned cron command, now all cron group are running. But I wanted to stop my custom group cron. Please tell me how to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below command:

```
bin/magento cron:remove --group ['group name']
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow below step it's working for me
You can by running cron remove command:

```
php bin/magento cron:remove ----group index
```

It will only remove cron tasks from crontab but not the exact cron codes/files.

If you wish to run the cron jobs again, you just need to run cron run command twice:
php bin/magento cron:run

The first time run is to discover cron tasks to run and the second time — to run the tasks themselves.
The second cron run must occur on or after the scheduled_at time for every task.